# Model Driven PowerApps

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerapps, power-automate, powerapps-modeldriven

I am developing a model driven Power App. I have an entity with a few person/group fields like "Updated By" and "Completed By". Is there a way for the App to recognize who is updating a record so that I can place that card into an MS Flow and send an email with the information of who updated the record? Or maybe fill out a field in the record itself of who last edited it?

Comment: Do you have follow up question?

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Model driven Power App (aka Dynamics 365 CRM) stores the last modified person & timestamp by Out-of-the-box design in the modified record itself. You can use that in MS Flow - Dynamic content while sending out an email.

> [image]

If you want to capture it in some additional field - you can do that also.